# Why am I wrong? (Question from Kleppner and Kolenkow )

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The question is:

2.7 Leaning pole
A pole of negligible mass leans against a wall, at angle θ with the horizontal. Gravity is directed down.

(a) Find the constraint relating the vertical acceleration of one end to the horizontal acceleration of the other.

(b) Now suppose that each end carries a pivoted mass M. Find the initial vertical and horizontal components of acceleration as the pole just begins to slide on the frictionless wall and floor. Assume that at the beginning of the motion the forces exerted by the rod are along the line of the rod. (As the motion progresses, the system rotates and the rod exerts sidewise forces.)

Here's my solution:
[image][image][image]

But I couldn't understand why my approach was wrong while deriving equation 3. Could someone please explain why we can't do it that way?

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I don't have any other source (teacher or friend) to know about it. Well this might not exactly be very conceptual but I think it is confusing. Could you suggest where can I ask for help now?

Comment: Your diagram shows the x and y axes with positive x to the right and positive y **upwards**.  Your equation of vertical motion (iii) does not follow this convention.

Comment: I got equation 3 by simplifying, Fsinθ-Mg=M (-y). This is considering that we took acceleration of lower end as positive i.e toward +x axis. Hence, the acceleration of upper end must be negative i.e towards -ve y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation (iii) is wrong. Since you have taken $y$ as +ve in the upward direction, double differentiating it would also yield $y''$ in the positive direction. Hence your equation must be,

$F\sin\theta - Mg = My''$

These are vector equations, adding a direction with each force component will clear your confusion.

Comment: I got equation 3 by simplifying, Fsinθ-Mg=M (-y''). This is considering that we took acceleration of lower end as positive i.e toward +x axis. Hence, the acceleration of upper end must be negative i.e towards -ve y-axis. Is this wrong. (I think I did consider the direction) .

Comment: I guess I understood what you're trying to explain. Thanks for help.

Comment: @suiz If you like this answer, you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You must not make a judgement about the direction of $\ddot y$ and allow the subsequent algebra to determine the sign of this acceleration.

The vector relationship is

$$m\ddot y \,\hat j = F \sin \theta \,\hat j - Mg \,\hat j $$

where $\ddot y$ is the **component** of the acceleration in the $\hat j$ direction.